# Allow a single Matlab instance to run

Tags: matlab

Whenever I double-click a `.m` files a new instance of Matlab is opened.
Is there any way to tell Matlab to keep every files in a single istance?

Matlab 2012a, Windows 8.

I only found an old guide that applies to XP. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/303080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this post from The Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-D9IA82/?solution=1-D9IA82), for Windows 7. The solution provides three suggested workarounds. The first one worked for me, so I'll try to summarize here.

**Solution**

This is likely caused by Windows default security settings on your *pathdef.m* file:

- From _Windows Explorer, navigate to *MATLABROOT\toolbox\local* (where *MATLABROOT* is the directory returned by running `matlabroot` from within MATLAB).
- Right click on the file *pathdef.m*, and select the *Security* tab.
- Click *Edit*, select the *Users* group, click *Full control*.
- Apply changes, close the properties Window, and restart MATLAB.

If you had modified Matlab to launch as Admin, set it back to launch as a User. This should do the trick.

For complete details, and additional soltions, check out the [original post](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-D9IA82/?solution=1-D9IA82).

Comment: Can you post what that link suggest ?

Comment: Let me know if this works for you, if not I can also post additional solutions from the list.

Comment: It isn't working for me on Windows 8 :(... It is already on Full control

Answer (score 0):

I tried solutions A and B provided by [MathWorks Support Team](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93468-why-is-a-new-instance-of-matlab-opened-when-i-double-click-on-a-matlab-file-in-windows-explorer-even) but none works for me. Then I downloaded [MATLAB File Association Fix](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51165-matlab-file-association-fix) by [Patrik Forssén](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/2631027-patrik-forssen) and my problem get solved like magic. Mine was MatLab R2017b, Windows 10.

Procedure for the same is:

1. Download the zip file. [MATLAB File Association Fix](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51165-matlab-file-association-fix)
2. Extract it and run matlab script named **associateFiles.m** in Matlab. By running this script, a new file with extension ***.reg** will be generated in the same folder.
3. Go to the folder and double click on this ***.reg** file. Registry will be updated.
4. Now restart Matlab.